# GPS turns on every time WiFi network is changed

Tags: wi-fi, gps, gps-tracking, samsung-galaxy-s-10, android-11

Whenever i change WiFi network, GPS just keeps turning on. I turned off GPS and **change system settings** permissions for every app, but it still keeps happening. **Recent location requests** shows that no apps have used that permission. Turning off google's **find my phone** also doesn't help. What is going on?

Device: Samsung Galaxy s10

Comment: Check the advanced location settings regarding if "Google Location Accuracy" is activated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to go to Settings -> Connections -> Wi-Fi -> Three-Dots-Menu -> Advanced -> Turn on Wifi automatically -> turn this setting off.

It seems like some devices claim access to GPS in order to find the available WiFi networks if this setting is activated.

Comment: Yeah, this is literally how High Accuracy Location Reporting works, by using a combination of GPS and WiFi. Most apps are making a call to Google Location services to get this which uses the WiFi and GPS to get a more accurate location than GPS alone, not the app itself which is doing it, it is just making a location request to the system. That doesn't mean the app can't see your available WiFi networks, because it can (otherwise WiFi scanner apps wouldn't work) but most are not looking at the WiFi itself.

Comment: No, that doesn't solve the issue.